# Disable colorcolumn on BufLeave

Tags: autocmd, colorcolumn

I would like to disable the colorcolumn in a buffer when switching to a different buffer. I try to perform this with a autocommand using the BufLeave Event.

In Neovim I use the following

```
local set_colorcolumn = function()
    local buf = vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()
    vim.notify("BufEnter " .. tostring(buf))
    vim.opt_local.colorcolumn = "80"
end
local unset_colorcolumn = function()
    local buf = vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()
    vim.notify("BufLeave " .. tostring(buf))
    vim.opt_local.colorcolumn = "0"
end

local colorcolumn_group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("CursorColumn", { clear = true })

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    { "BufEnter" },
    { pattern = "*.lua", group = colorcolumn_group, callback = set_colorcolumn }
)

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    { "BufLeave" },
    { pattern = "*.lua", group = colorcolumn_group, callback = unset_colorcolumn }
)
```

In Vim it would be

```
augroup colcol
    au BufEnter *.lua :setlocal colorcolumn=80
    au BufLeave *.lua :set colorcolumn=0
augroup end
```

In both cases the colorcolumn persists when switching buffers. I also tried to call redraw in the neovim case, with no success.

[image: Actual Behavior]

[image: Expected Behavior]

Can anybody explain why I'm experiencing this behavior? Is this to be expected.

Comment: Works for me in vim https://asciinema.org/a/ESUgdzhHiPKQevlSG534rvOyH

Comment: Pls clarify if it only doesn't work in neovim and you need it there.

Comment: How are you switching buffers? Could it be a missing `++nested`?

Comment: I have tested on Neovim and it seems to work fine.

Comment: It works in thew way shown in the asciinema shown by Maxim Kim, but it does not work if you take the steps that I've described above. Even in the asciinema it does not work as expected when switching the first time to the split buffer. The colorcolumn persists the first time, when creating the split. 1. open a lua file
2. open a help page e.g. :h BufLeave Then for that time it does not work. But then when you switch between the two open buffers it works again.

Comment: It seems to work when switching buffers with e.g. `<C-W>w`  but not when opening `:help` (which is what OP did). Maybe related to the events `:help` fires? (BTW, I tried with `*` as file name pattern.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a miss understanding about the pattern. The code only make the modification when you switch to a `lua` file.

I would try:

```lua
local set_colorcolumn = function()
    local buf = vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()
    vim.notify("BufEnter " .. tostring(buf))
    vim.opt_local.colorcolumn = "80"
end
local unset_colorcolumn = function()
    local buf = vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()
    vim.notify("BufLeave " .. tostring(buf))
    vim.opt_local.colorcolumn = "0"
end

local colorcolumn_group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("CursorColumn", { clear = true })

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    { "BufEnter" },
    { pattern = "*", group = colorcolumn_group, callback = set_colorcolumn }
)

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    { "BufLeave" },
    { pattern = "*", group = colorcolumn_group, callback = unset_colorcolumn }
)
```

Comment: This doesn't represent my usecase. I want a specific colorcolumn per filetype and by default no colorcolumn. Your proposal will enable colorcolumn for any filetype including e.g. vimdoc. But I would want a defined colorcolumn for specific filea like lua, but only if the cursor is in the buffer.